# Why am I getting a `MissingSchemaError` when rearranging file structure?

Tags: angularjs, testing, mongoose, mocha.js

I am trying to write a test in angular-fullstack, and I have the files arranged as so:

> Test:
>
> - client
>
>   - server
>   - user
>
>     - model.js
>   - article
>
>     - article.js

When I run `grunt test:server`, I get the error:

```
 MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Article".
```

However, If I rearrange the files like this:

> Test:
>
> - client
>
>   - server
>   - user
>
>     - model.js
>     - article.js

then everything works.

Why is this? How can I get it to work with the first file structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same Problem today.

I solved it with this statement

```
app = require('../../../server'),
```

because the server.js is iterating over all js-Files in the model folder and requires them

The reason why this is not required in the user/model.js -Test that comes with the scaffolding,
is because of the folder scruture.
the first test is the server/thing/api.js - Test that requires the server.
After that the user/models.js test is executed and all the schemas are already loaded.

In your case Article are excuted before the thing/api.js-Test. 
Just put a "z" before the Article-Folder and it will work :-)

Answer (score 1):

To be absolutely clear for others following this question, you have to put the

```
var app = require('../../../server');
```

line in the test file for the model you are trying to test. So for example:

```
// You have to require "app" or shit blows up when you run "grunt serve"
var app = require('../../../server');

var should = require('should'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Luggage = mongoose.model('Luggage');

...
```